# CIE IGCSE Pre-release Material

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

The CIE IGCSE Pre-release Material has been dispatched it asks children who are usually at the age of 15 to perform gigantic tasks in programming in 1 month which is not always possible as the level required is sometimes too high. The tasks for this year are:

A farmer records the milk production of a herd of cows.

Every cow has a **unique** 3-digit identity code.

Each cow can be milked twice a day, seven days a week.

The volume of the milk from each cow is recorded in liters correct to one decimal place (yield) every time the cow is milked.

The size of the herd is **fixed**.

At the end of the week, the total and the average yield for each cow for the week is calculated.

The farmer identifies the cow that has produced the most milk that week.

The farmer also identifies any cows that have produced less than 12 liters of milk on four or more days that week.

A program is required to record the yield for each cow every time it is milked, calculate the total weekly volume of milk for the herd and the average yield **per cow** in a week.

The program must also identify the cow with the best yield that week and identify any cow with a yield of fewer than 12 liters of milk for four or more days that week.

Write and test a program or programs for the farmer.Your program of programs must include the appropriate prompts for the entry of data.

Error messages and other output need to be set out clearly and understandably.

All variables, constants and other identifiers must have meaningful names

You will need to complete these three tasks. Each task must be fully tested.

TASK 1 – Record the yield

Write a program for TASK 1 to record the milk yields for a week. The program records and stores the identify code number and the yield every time a cow is milked.

TASK 2 – Calculate the statistics

Using your recorded data from TASK 1, calculate and display the total weekly volume of milk for the herd to nearest while liter. Calculate and display the average yield per cow in a week to the nearest whole liter.

TASK 3 – Identify the most productive and cows that are producing a low volume of milk.
Extend TASK 2 to identify and display the identity code number and weekly yield of the cow that has produced the most milk. Also identify and display the identity code numbers of any cows with a yield of less than 12 liters of milk for four days or more in the week.

I tried to solve it using Python and this is what I reached

```
# Recording the yield
Cow = []
Yield = []
Cows = int(input("How many cows are in the herd?  "))
Day = 0     #to configure the milking
for i in range(14):
if i%2 == 1:
    Milking = "Second"
else:
    Milking = "First"
    Day += 1
print("Day ", Day, "; ", Milking, " milking")
for i in range(Cows):
    while True:
        try:
            Code = int(input("Enter code: "))
            if Code > 999 or Code < 100:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a 3-digit code please")
        else:
            Cow.append(Code)
            while True:
                try:
                    Y = float(input("Enter volume of milk in litres: "))    #A range check for yield can be added
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a positive number")
                else :
                    Yield.append(Y)
                    break
            print(Yield)
            print(Cow)
            break
Total = 0 #Finding the Total and Average
for i in range(len(Yield)):
Total += Yield[i]
Average = Total/Cows
round(Total, 0)
round(Average, 0)
print("Total weekly volume of milk: ", int(Total), " litres")
print("Average yield per cow: ", int(Average), " litres")
print(len(Cow))

#Identifying most productive and low producing cows
Total = []
LessMilk = ""
YieldOnDay = 0
Milking = 0
for j in range(Cows):
T = 0
Days = 0
Cow = Cow[j]                    #A cow chosen
for i in range(len(Cow)):
    if Cow[i] == Cow:
        T += Yield[i]         #Incrementing the total for each cow
        YieldOnDay += Yield[i]
        Milking += 1
        if Milking == 2:            # 2 since checking for days, not `milkings
            if YieldOnDay < 12: #Checking if yield is less than 12 Days += 1 Milking = 0 YieldOnDay = 0 if Days > 3:        #Low yield for 4 or more days
                LessMilk = LessMilk + str(Cow[j]) + ", "
Total.append(T)

print(Total)
for i in range(Cows):
if Total[i] == max(Total):
    print("Cow ", Cow[i], " has the highest yield of ", Total[i], " litres")

print("Cows which produced less than 12 litres of milk: " , LessMilk)
```

As you can see I was not able to solve the unique code problem and the average per cow (shown in bold above). My code for the last part doesn't work. It shows after I reach midway in the interactive shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\*****\******\*******\********************\*********************", line 52, in <module>
    for i in range(len(Cow)):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't know why. I tried everything it still doesn't work.

I wanted to make lists based on the number of cows in the herd ie. the first input by I didn't know how.
Also would it be better if I use arrays instead of lists?Is Python a good option for this task or not?

Thank you very much for reading and keeping all the IGCSE students around the world in your kindest considerations.Your help would really be appreciated by me and by all IGCSE students around the world.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late, but right before the error line, you have the line `Cow = Cow[j]`, which wipes your entire `Cow` list and replaces it with one cow. That's why the next line raises an error - a single cow isn't a list, so you can't get its `len`. For future reference, make your variable names really clear so that you don't confuse them. For example, you could rename `Cows` something like `n_cows` (for "number of cows"), and you could rename `Cow` to `cows_list`. Best of luck with your IGCSEs!

<sub>PS: Also, keeping your questions short will help find answers more quickly. Just a quick description of your problem is enough - you don't need to post the entire project.</sub>